# How does Matrix Translate work?

Tags: c#, vector, matrix, point

I'm playing with `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix` and have a hard time to figure out how to move a point by specified vector.
For example I would like to use `Matrix` to move a point `(1,1)` by a vector `(2,2)` so that after the transformation the point would have coordinates `(3,3)`. However following code does not seem to work, the point still has origin coordinates (I'm probably missing something fundamental here):

```
var point = new PointF(1F, 1F);
var matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Translate(2F,2F);            
matrix.TransformPoints(new[]{point});
```

Could anyone explain how the proper transformation looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're passing a new object to `TransformPoints`, which will eventually get lost.

Try changing your code to

```
var point = new PointF(1F, 1F);
var matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Translate(2F,2F);         
PointF[] aPoints = { point };   
matrix.TransformPoints(aPoints);

point = aPoints[0];
```

Notice the change in the last line.

Comment: Thanks, but this code won't compile.
I'm passing an implicitly typed array which is equivalent to 
`new PointF[]{point}`

Comment: Oh the Reflector did tell the truth the array was indeed lost and the result of transformation is stored in it. Your answer did really help, thank's a lot.

Comment: @miensol, sorry got it wrong, though the direction was correct, see edit for the fixed code